# When should/shouldn't I grant explicit write access to a low rep user?

Tags: discussion

It generally happens that a comments on questions/answers stretch too long.This may happen due to improper/inadequate information provided by OP or for clarification asked by some users or for whatsoever reason.

The system generally suggests to avoid long discussion and use discussion on chat as an alternative.

But only users with 20+ rep can post in chat.Under 20 rep users can be granted explicit write access to a chat room.

My question is: **When should I and when should I not grant explicit write access to a user?**. I have considered few condition ahead.

- Should I do this for only those posts which have been upvoted?
- Only for user with >1 reputation.

So what are your views on this?

Answer (score 3):

That feature is *only* there to allow users with less than 20 reputation to chat temporarily. This is usually for when a comment discussion is getting too long and the discussion should be moved to chat, but one of the users doesn't have the required reputation.

As far as I know, this feature can only be used by moderators, but it definitely can't be used by anyone that isn't a room owner of the room.

Answer (score 3):

As the others have already told you, the question is moot since only moderators can do this. Not even a room owner can unless they happen to be a mod. There is a feature request for this on the main meta site, you can go and upvote it if you would like it to be implemented:

[Allow inviting people with rep < 20 to private chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111942/203101)

Answer (score 1):

That option doesn't do anything in public rooms when used by a non-mod, a regular user can't give a <20 rep user access to chat, it simply does not work.

So you should never do that, as it doesn't do anything useful.